# Using MYSQL why does this give me the wrong time stamp?

Tags: mysql, database, time, max

Using the following snippet:-

```
SELECT MAX(data),Epoch_Time from MyTable where Epoch_Time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-600)
```

I can find the maximum data from the last rolling 10 minutes, but it returns the time that it started from, not the time of the maximum.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's expected because MAX(...) finds maximum value, but that doesn't mean that the epoch_time will be the corresponding time for that maximum value. In order to do that you can join with a dependent subquery:

```
SELECT mt.data, mt.Epoch_Time
from MyTable mt
where mt.data = (
   SELECT 
      MAX(data) as mmax
   from MyTable mt2
   where mt2.Epoch_Time > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 600));
```

Comment: The subquery doesn't need to be dependent. Edited.

Comment: Hell, it doesn't even need to be a subquery (although it is generally more efficient to use one)

Comment: Wow, I thought that it would be quick! I Had to do the school run, and when I got back, there is the answer!
Thanks for the quick response.